# for loops returned with a ">"

Tags: linux

I would like to extract all the tar.gz files in a directory.

I have searched in the internet and used the command:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -xzvf $i; done
```

However, the terminal returned with a > at the following line.

Can somebody enlighten me with what is the situation here? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not reproducible here.

Comment: Hi n.m., could you explain further?

Comment: On my machines this line doesn't do what you claim it does. (That's what "not reproducible" normally means.) It does not display any `>`. In fact it just works as intended, and I don't see a reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: Your command looks fine. The `>` prompt typically comes up when a shell command is incomplete, essentially asking you to type the rest (e.g. if you were to leave off the `done`). I suspect another problem. Are you *sure* this is the exact command you typed (did you e.g. leave out a semicolon or something)? Did you type it or did you copy + paste it? Can you post the output of `ls`? What shell are you using (post the output of `echo $0`)?

Answer (score 1):

Does your tar.gz files have spaces or special charas in their names? just a guess, try this:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -xzvf "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm your solution should work in my opinion. You can try something simpler

```
ls *.tar.gz | xargs -L 1 tar -xzvf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find -name '*.tar.*' | xargs -I% tar -xvf %
```

Comment: @JasonC now everything is f9

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to specify the output folder for your zip files. 
This is what the > stands for normally.

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar xvzf $i -C path/to/output/directory; done
```

This did the trick when i used it some weeks ago.

Comment: This is only necessary if the current directory is not writable.

Answer (score 0):

No one suggested find -print0 | xargs -0 for filenames with spaces, here it is:

```
/tmp/foo$ ls -1
a.tar.gz
b.tar.gz
c and d.tar.gz
/tmp/foo$ find . -name "*.tar.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} tar -xzvf {}
a
c
d
b
/tmp/foo$ ls -1
a
a.tar.gz
b
b.tar.gz
c
c and d.tar.gz
d
```

Your solution will fail on my input data because of the file "c and d.tar.gz" which contains a space but maybe that's not the error you experienced. The one from A.M.D will work.